# Get random data from each category with different limit for each category php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one question table with `id`, `type`, `question`, `option1 .. 4` and `answer` fields. Have three types of questions A,B and C.

I have to take random 7 questions for A and B type each and 6 random questions for type C. Show total 20 questions for each test.

I have to show only one question at a time and next on next button. So I am using pagination for this. So i have to add `$limit`, `$start` at the end on mysql query. How can I write a single query for this.

I wrote two queries like:

```
1:
(select * from dgm_questions Where ques_type IN('A') Order by rand() ASC Limit 7) union (select * from dgm_questions Where ques_type
IN('B') Order by rand() ASC Limit 7) union (select * from
dgm_questions Where ques_type IN('C') Order by rand() ASC
Limit 6)

2: select ques_id, ques_type from dgm_questions Where ques_type IN('A','B','C') Order by rand() ASC Limit 20
```

First query give me total 20 questions but not able to add `$limit`, `$start` for pagination and second query not shows limit 7 for A, B type liimit 6 for C type.

How can I write query for this?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a session solution (if that's an option), since you don't want to select 20 random questions for every request (when you click on the next button), I guess, which would happen if you work with pagination.

So my suggestion would be to fetch 20 random questions according to your criteria and store them (actually just the IDs) in a session and load from there for every single question page:

```
// on the questionaire start
// depending on wich library you use fetch the random question ids
// with your sql statement
SELECT ques_id FROM dgm_questions WHERE ques_type IN('A') ORDER BY rand() ASC Limit 7
UNION
SELECT ques_id FROM dgm_questions WHERE ques_type IN('B') ORDER BY rand() ASC Limit 7
UNION
SELECT ques_id FROM dgm_questions WHERE ques_type IN('C') ORDER BY rand() ASC Limit 6

// assuming the result is stored in $question_ids
// you can shuffle those questions, so they're not in type order anymore
shuffle($question_ids)

// save question ids in session
$_SESSION['question_ids'] = $question_ids;
$_SESSION['current_question_index'] = 0;

// on each request
"SELECT * FROM dgm_questions WHERE ques_id = " . $_SESSION['question_ids'][$_SESSION['current_question_index']];
$_SESSION['current_question_index']++;
```

Now, this is just to give you an overall idea how to tackle the problem. Keep in mind, that if you sort by random() MySQL always sorts the **full table** before selecting the records which can be a performance killer on huge tables. If that's a concern there are [other solutions](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/).

Hope this helps!